Determining Maximum Ratio Between Arithmetic Mean and Geometric Mean, subject to Boundary Conditions
This problem has been bothering me for a while - I have tried to attack the problem through many means, and I'll detail some of my attempts here, but I have come to no viable conclusion (probably due to my lack of expertise in multivariate optimisation problems).
Consider $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ (we can assume $n$ to be large) with $x_i>0$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, and the following function:
$$
S(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{\prod_{k=1}^nx_k^{1/n}}.
$$
I want to find the asymptotic maximum of the sum in $n$, subject to the following boundary conditions:
\begin{align}
&x_1=1,
\\& x_i \leq 1, \hspace{1mm} 2 \leq i \leq n,
\\& x_i \leq (j-i+1)\prod_{k=i}^j x_k^{1/(j-i+1)}, \hspace{1mm} 1 \leq i <j \leq n.
\end{align}
An extremely trivial upper bound can be found. Using the fact that $x_i \leq 1$, we get
\begin{align*}
S(x_1,\dots,x_n) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{1/n}} \leq n^2,
\end{align*}
where the final inequality comes from the fact that $x_1=1 \leq n\prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{1/n}$. This bound is quite clearly very loose, however, since we have both used the conditions $x_i=1, 2 \leq i \leq n$ and $\prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{1/n}=n^{-1}$, both of which cannot be true simultaneously.
By a similar though slightly more careful method, we can also show that
$$
S(x_1,\dots,x_n) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n ((i-1)^{i-1}(n-i+1)^{n-i+1})^{1/n}=O(n^2),
$$
though again this bound is loose for similar reasons to before.
An easy observation is that the maximum of the sum must occur when all the $x_i$ are either maximal or minimal (by observing that the function $f(x)=Ax^{(n-1)/n}+Bx^{-1/n}$ attains its local maximum when $x$ is either maximal or minimal, when $A,B>0$). Another observation is by an inductive proof, we have $x_i \geq i^{-1}\prod_{k=2}^i k^{-1/(k-1)}>i^{-1-\log(i)}$, though I don't know how helpful this is.
I have a feeling (which may be unfounded) that we have
\begin{align*}
S(x_1,\dots,x_n) \leq O\left(\frac{n^2}{\log(n)}\right),
\end{align*}
for large $n$. A final possible helpful insight is as follows: suppose that $S(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ attains its maximum for some $x_i$ being maximal, i.e. $x_i=1$. Then
\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{\prod_{k \neq i} x_k^{1/n}}+\sum_{l \neq i}\frac{x_l}{\prod_{k \neq i}x_k^{1/n}} \geq \frac{m_i^{n-1}}{\prod_{k \neq i}x_k^{1/n}}+m_i^{-1}\sum_{l \neq i}\frac{x_i}{\prod_{k \neq i}x_k^{1/n}}
\\& \iff S(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{l=1}^n \frac{x_l}{\prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{1/n}} \leq \prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{-1/n}\frac{1-m_i^{n-1}}{m_i^{-1}-1}+\frac{x_i}{\prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{1/n}}\\&<n\frac{1-m_i^{n-1}}{m_i^{-1}-1}+n,
\end{align*}
where $m_i=i^{-(1+\log(i))/n}$ and we have used the fact that $x_i/\prod_{k=1}^n x_k^{1/n} \leq 1/\prod_{k=1}^{n}x_k^{1/n} \leq n$. Therefore if $\frac{1-m_i^{n-1}}{m_i^{-1}-1}<O(n/\log(n))$, my claim of $S(x_1,\dots,x_n) \leq O(n^2/\log(n))$ at its maximum would hold true. Since $\frac{1-m_i^{n-1}}{m_i^{-1}-1}$ is monotonically decreasing in $i$ (for $2 \leq i \leq n$), if we wanted to find a contradiction to my claim that $S(x_1,\dots,x_n) \leq O(n^2/\log(n))$ at its maximum, we would need $x_i$ to be set at their minimal value for all $i \geq i_{\text{min}}$, where $i_{\text{min}}$ is the smallest value of $i$ such that $\frac{1-m_i^{n-1}}{m_i^{-1}-1}<O(n/\log(n))$ (I think that $n\frac{1-m_i^{n-1}}{m_i^{-1}-1}<n^2/\log(n)$ when $i>2\sqrt{n/\log(n)}$, though I have not formally proven this fact). Again, not sure if this helps.
I would like some help, or maybe just some hints, as to how to solve this problem. I have tried using the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker theorem approach, though since $n$ is just some variable integer, this method seems very difficult. Also, perhaps $S(x_1,\dots,x_n)<O(n^2)$ is the best possible upper bound.
I apologise in advance if I have used any terms incorrectly, or omitted any useful information useful to this problem. I can adjust the post accordingly if I have made any errors. If anyone can suggest anything at all regarding this problem that may be useful, I would be eternally grateful, as it is a major problem I've been looking at as part of one of my papers on positive-definite quadratic forms.
